# 'Nous préparer pour....' (message d'E. Macron)

Tags: grammaire

> **Nous préparer** pour ne connaître aucune coupure de gaz ou d'électricité cet hiver, c'est ce que nous faisons. Les solutions sont entre nos mains : être au rendez-vous de la solidarité et de la sobriété. (source :  https://www.facebook.com/EmmanuelMacron).

Je comprends le sens de la tournure 'nous préparer' mais je ne peux pas l'expliquer grammaticalement.

Comment: La nature de la difficulté n'est pas très claire. Il s'agit de la reprise du sujet: *Emmanuel est mon meilleur ami.* -> *Emmanuel, c'est mon meilleur ami.*

Comment: *Te poser une question, c'est ce que tu as fait.*

Comment: @RogerVadim : Sorry for not being clear. I guess you answered my question:-)! May be I was not familiar with this turn. Thanks.

Comment: @jlliagre Nice example:-)! Thanks!

Comment: @Dimitris apparently the correct term is *redoublement de sujet*, see, e.g., [here](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/redoublement-et-omission-du-sujet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est probablement le pronom réfléchi *nous* de l'infinitif du verbe *préparer* qui motive ta question.

La phrase suit ce modèle :

> *Me préparer, c'est ce que je fais.*  (Je me prépare)
> *Te préparer, c'est ce que tu fais.*  (Tu te prépares)
> *Se préparer, c'est ce qu'il/elle fait.*
> *Se préparer, c'est ce qu'on fait.*
> ***Nous préparer, c'est ce que nous faisons.*** (nous nous préparons)
> *Vous préparer, c'est ce que vous faites.*
> *Se préparer, c'est ce qu'ils/elles font.*

Quelque chose de similaire en anglais :

> *Making something of ourselves, that's what we do in this country.*  [Barack Obama, 2013](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/blog/2013/10/25/p-tech-proof-what-can-be-accomplished-we-ve-got-have-courage-do-it)

Comment: Bravo! Tu as bien compris ma problèmatique:-)! (J'aime bien l'emploi du verbe 'motive'!)

Comment: Peut-être Macron copie Obama:-)!

Comment: Macron s'est certainement beaucoup inspiré d'Obama. J'espère que ça n'aboutira pas, après, là-aussi, un deuxième mandat présidentiel sans majorité absolue, jusqu'à un(e) successeur à la Trump...